# Does Castle ActiveRecord's ActiveRecordMediator<> support LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

Does Castle ActiveRecord's `ActiveRecordMediator<>` class support LINQ queries? I couldn't find any method that returns an `IQueryable<>`. My domain objects can't inherit from `ActiveRecordLinqBase<>` due to their design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a separate static class for that - ActiveRecordLinq. Example:

```
from w in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<MyEntity>() select w;
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that.